# Manipulating data arrays and adding noise

Tags: python, arrays, normal-distribution, fits

I just cannot seem to get this right! :-(

I have a code that is supposed to read in a .fits file, add normally distributed noise to it, and then re-save that code. So far, it just does not seem to be working at all. There's a lot of extra code, so I only posted the portion that's relevant. Assume that everything that this slice of code needs to read in exists, because it does. The goal of this code is to take a .fits file and add normally distributed noise to the pixels, then save that file. "poisson" is a previously inputted variable, i.e. a "poisson" value of 1 corresponds to one standard deviation from the mean of zero. Yes, the word "poisson" is a bit of a misnomer, and I should really rehaul my code to amend that.

My first issue is . . . what does im0 = im[0] mean? It doesn't seem like it's the first row of pixels in the .fits file, because when I change the integer in the brackets to anything besides "0", I get an index error. On top of that, the normalNoise = np.random.normal(0,poisson) method is incomplete because I'm missing a third parameter, "size" (tuple of ints) and I have no idea what that means. My images are 130 pixels x 130 pixels, if that means anything.

```
    im = pf.open(name)
    im0 = im[0]
    normalNoise = np.random.normal(0,poisson)
    print im0.data
    test = im0.data + normalNoise
    print test
    im0.data = test
    stringee = 'NOISE'
    pf.writeto(stringee+str(poisson)+name, data=test, clobber=True, header=im0.header)
print poisson
```

This should ideally spit out the same image but with added noise, except it doesn't!

Comment: Try printing out stuff to know what it holds?! Also, correct the indentation of your code.

Comment: Aah the indentation is as is because the listed code falls under a previous "for" loop. When I print out im0.data or test, I get nonsensical stuff, and I definitely do not get any sort of added noise. I'm thoroughly confused at the moment.

Comment: We would like to know that nonsensical stuff, please add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the underlying library, but if pf is a FITS file, im[0] is probably
creating a reference to the primary HDU; if there is only a primary HDU (as for
any simple-minded FITS file with only a single image), any higher index leads to an error.